# Compare cells including character

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to compare 2 cells, which have different character but the same value. Thanks for help. Great would be with conditionnal formatting.

different colors
different style: strikethrough
....

[!excel[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hilTC.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hilTC.png)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please add your code.

Comment: UNICODE, CODE, Conditional formatting - Duplicates (unique)

Comment: You should add information by [editing your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59986867/edit) instead of putting it in comments

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried comparing the (Unicode) character code?

[See Asc / AscW Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-basic-6/aa262678(v=vs.60)?redirectedfrom=MSDN)

In Cells, you could also use

```
=Unicode(A1)
```

Comment: Could you post examples for the characters you are using? I can't identify them from the image.